# How can I create a CSR like this using OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl, attributes, csr, req

I got a CSR example from some customer. They are asking how to use openssl command to create such CSR. I can create an CSR but I can't create a similar CSR that containing same attributes part.

```
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 2 (0x1)
        Subject: DC = WAPI, C = CN, O = HTKC001, OU = HTKC002, CN = HTKC002@AE
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
            Unable to load Public Key
6768:error:100D7010:elliptic curve routines:eckey_pub_decode:EC lib:../openssl-1.1.1d/crypto/ec/ec_ameth.c:151:
6768:error:0B09407D:x509 certificate routines:x509_pubkey_decode:public key decode error:../openssl-1.1.1d/crypto/x509/x_pubkey.c:125:
        Attributes:
            2.16.840.1.113732.2      :40:77:a9:a3:bb:f0
    Signature Algorithm: 1.2.156.11235.1.1.1
         30:35:02:19:00:af:0f:99:40:60:7d:8d:50:a6:43:27:41:01:
         32:c3:f3:67:bf:b8:db:1f:89:8f:f9:02:18:6f:77:3d:7a:af:
         fe:c1:fa:7b:cf:f5:c8:2e:ac:39:e2:04:d7:19:7e:10:39:8b:
         29
```

Here is the command I tried :

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -sha256 -addext "2.16.840.1.113732.2 = 00:11:22:33:44:55"

openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -sha256 -reqexts "2.16.840.1.113732.2=00:11:22:33:44:55"
```

for both I got errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ new_oids ]
....
xxxxx  = 1.2.3.4.5

[ req_attributes ]
....
xxxxx  = enter your new item xxxxx
```

Finally I changed my configration file ,and fixed my problem.